# Javascript Using iframe?

Tags: java, javascript, html, ajax, jsp

I'm using the jsp of a popup window using the javascript with iframe to show a table of multiple records.When i disabled the table of multiple records,it doesn't prevent the  onclick function (hyperlink).

## The sample code is :

```
    <tr>         
<td colspan="2" class="fieldBG" align="left" valign="middle" width="100%" style="padding:2x">
              <iframe name="targetIFrame" id="targetIFrame" src ="/jsp/targetScheduleIFrame.jsp?companyId=<%=zoniacSession.getUserInfo().getCompanyInfo().getCompanyid()%>&loginEmployeeId=<%=zoniacSession.getUserInfo().getEmployeeId()%>" scrolling="yes" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0"></iframe></td>
            </tr>
```

1.The above code is in popup window it links to another page namely targetscheduleIFrame.jsp

### 2.The targetscheduleIFrame.jsp page contains the below code:

```
     for (int k=0; k<jobTriggers.length; k++)
                        {
                         Trigger trigger = jobTriggers[k];
%>

    <tr>
     <th width="4%" class="fieldBG" align="center" valign="top" style="padding:2px">     
      <zoniac:rect class="zoniac_Edit" fillcolor="#ffffff" style='cursor:hand' strokecolor="#000080"  onselectstart="return false" onClick="javascript:deleteQuartzTrigger('<%=trigger.getGroup()%>','<%=trigger.getName()%>');return false;" onMouseOver="window.status='Click here to go to Page'; return true" title="Delete Schedule">DEL</zoniac:rect>&nbsp;
     </th>
     <td width="14%" class="fieldBG" align="left" valign="top" style="padding:2px">
      &nbsp;<a id="hrefDiv" href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="popupWindow('/jsp/targetViewInformation.jsp','TargetViewInfo','700','500','no','no');" class="smallModuleTextLink"><%=trigger.getGroup() + trigger.getName()%></a>
     </td>     
     <td width="9%" class="fieldBG" align="left" valign="top" style="padding:2px">
      &nbsp;All days 
     </td>
     <td width="6%" class="fieldBG" align="left" valign="top" style="padding:2px">
      &nbsp;<%=(String)trigger.getJobDataMap().get("TriggerTime")%>
     </td>
    <td width="20%" class="fieldBG" align="left" valign="top" style="padding:2px">
     <%=trigger.getDescription()%>
    </td>
    <td width="12%" class="fieldBG" align="left" valign="top" style="padding:2px">
     &nbsp;Jan-22-2010 10:22 AM
    </td>
    </tr>

<%
   }
            }
} else {
%>
   <tr>
    <td colspan="6" class="fieldBG" width="100%" align="center" valign="top" style="padding:2px">
      <b>No Records Found</b>
    </td>
   </tr>
<%
}
%>
```

### What I really Wants:

1.The jsp contains two radio button using inputs to the iframe ,whether it's onclick works or not.
2.The onclick will work one scenario, it will disable another scenario of depends upon the input of radio buttons.

Comment: How can i disabled the onclick function when using the iframe ?

Comment: I'm not sure I quite understand you'r problem, can you post some code of what you've done so we can try and help?

Comment: Depends upon your question ,now i posted the code to addition.

Answer (score 0):

In the parent page which has the iframe, you may have coded the javascript function `popupWindow(...)`

I suggest you add a radio button check before you push it to the window like

```
function popupWindow(........){

if(/*see if the radio is checked*/){
   // your code here to open the new window
}

}
```